# How do I access a property that I added during runtime to an object?

Tags: javascript, promise

[image]

In this example I added the property "col_id_3" to the Object. Later I want to access it. Eventhough I can see the property "col_id_3" is there (see picture), I can't access it with `Object.col_id_3`. JavaScript returns `undefined`. How can I access it instead? How can I make that attribute "stick" to the object?

```
myFunction: function(){
      return db.allDocs({include_docs: true}, function(err, response) {
        var myArray =[];
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw new Error(console.error("error"));
        } else {

          return Promise.all(response.rows.map(function(row){           
            if(row.doc.type == 'myAttribute') {
              row.myNewlyAddedProperty = {id: row.doc._id,
                name: row.doc.data.name,
                isValid: false
              };

              myAsynchFunction(row.qc)
              .then(anotherAsynchFunction(row.qc), function(error) {
                console.error("handle error: "+error.stack);
                throw error;
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("handle error in catch case: "+error.stack);
              });
            }
          }));
        }
      })
      .then(function (arrayResults) {
        var onlyFilteredResults = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayResults.rows.length; i++){
          var changedInput = arrayResults.rows[i];
          if (arrayResults.rows[i].doc.type == 'myAttribute') {
            console.log(changedInput); // here I can see my newly add Attribute
            console.log(changedInput.myNewlyAddedProperty); // here I can't access my newly attribute anymore
            console.log(Object.keys(changedInput)); //here my newly added Attribute isn't listed

          }
```

Comment: You have to show the whole flow of the code, you are probably overwriting the object without noticing.

Comment: Unless the OP is actually trying to use `Object.col_id_3` to access the property.

Comment: No, I don't. In one line I write console.log(Object); in the very next line I write console.log(Object.addedProperty); In one console log it's there. In the next it's not there. I'm just console log. I don't overwrite anything.

Comment: @Andy : So it's not possible to access that property via Object.col_id_3? How do I access it instead?

Comment: You need to assign your object a name like: `var myObj = { name: 'Andy' }` and then you can access the object like `myObj.name`, or `myObj['name']`. Unless your data is coming through an AJAX request then it will have the argument you specified in the callback, usually `response`, so `response.name`, or whatever.

Comment: Can't really do much without the code. Please keep the title to the point.

Comment: `console.log` shows you the object's state at *expansion time*, not at *log time*. So, clearly `changedInput` has `myNewlyAddedProperty` at the time you click to expand the logged object, but not when you actually make the `log` call.

Comment: @Andy: Wouldn't that overwrite my existing Object? How do I add 'name' to my exisiting object?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Andy thought you were *literally* running the code `Object.col_id_3`. The [built-in constructor `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) doesn't have a `col_id_3` property. You hadn't shown any code at the time, and weren't using a traditional metasyntactic variable like `foo`, so it seemed like a perfectly plausible explanation.

Comment: @thadeuszlay What is eventually returned from these promises: `myAsynchFunction(row.qc).then(anotherAsynchFunction(row.qc),...`? From this, It doesn't appear that `row` is the value accumulated but `row.qc` is. Also, if `anotherAsynchFunction` is an async function how are you sure it returns a function in time to be used by the `then` for `myAsynchFunction`? Seems like that would be a race condition.

Comment: One obvious problem I can see here is your `map` callback doesn't actually return a value (so you're just doing `Promise.all([undefined, undefined, ...])`). I unsure that's what's causing your problem.

Comment: @apsillers: It does return a value. In fact it should change the value of myNewlyAddedAttribute. It does everything correctly. The problem is I can't access it....

Comment: @thadeuszlay This is not related to your immediate problem, but it does not return a value. Your code has exactly two uses of the `return` keyword, and neither of them are inside of the `map` callback. You're functionally using `map` as a kind of `forEach`. `map`'s callback expects a return value to use in the output array. Right now, you are supplying no values to the output array (passed into `Promise.all`) because your `map` callback returns nothing. It's not causing your current problem, but it may cause problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` shows you the object's state at expansion time, not at log time. So, `changedInput` has `myNewlyAddedProperty` at the time you click to expand the logged object, but not when you actually make the `log` call.

Your problem is that you are using *both* a callback and a promise for `db.allDocs`. Assuming you're using PouchDB here, the promise results before the callback runs:

```
db.allDocs({}, function() { console.log("callback"); })
  .then(function() { console.log("promise") })
```

This code will log `"promise"` first and then log `"callback"`. Therefore, your `.then(function (arrayResults) { ... })` is running before your `db.allDocs(..., function(err, response) { ... })` callback. The solution here is to not use a callback with `allDocs` and use a promise instead:

```
db.allDocs(...)
.then(function(response) {
    var myArray =[];
    ...
    return response;
})
.then(function (arrayResults) {
    var onlyFilteredResults = [];
    ...
});
```

Also, your `response.rows.map` callback does not return any value, so `Promise.all` gets an array of `undefined` values. I assume you want to `return myAsynchFunction(row.qc).then(...)`.

Comment: Could you explain why my Promise.all() gets an array of undefined values? I debugged the promises and the asynchronous functions within the promises.all(). The functions do process values. How is that possible if the Promise.all() gets an array of undefined values?

Comment: @thadeuszlay The callback to `map` does *run*, but it doesn't return anything, so the result of the `map` call is an array of `undefined` values. `myAsynchFunction(row.qc).then(...)` yields a promise, but that promise is never supplied to `Promise.all`. Looking closer at your code, your `Promise.all` result is never used for anything, so it doesn't matter. I'm actually not sure why you're using `Promise.all` at all; it doesn't seem to do anything. If the `return Promise.all(...)` were inside of a promise, it might make sense, but now it's just the unused return value of a callback.

Comment: @thadeuszlay Or, wait, did you mean for `.then(function (arrayResults) {` to be on the `Promise.all`? It's on `allDocs`. If you move that `then` it inside the `allDocs` callback and put it on the `Promise.all` (and made the `map` callback actually return promises instead of `undefined`), that could work, too.

Comment: @thadeuszlay In short, right now, `Promise.all` is resolving *after* all of your `map` callback calls, but *before* before any of your `myAsynchFunction` calls resolve. If you `return` the promise produced by `myAsynchFunction().then()`, it will be supplied to `Promise.all`, and the `Promise.all` will wait to resolve until all of those promises are done.

Comment: @ apsillers: allDocs should retrieve data from a database (PouchDB). Promise.all() should iterate through that data, and filter these data according to certain criteria and change the values of some of their properties. The myAsynchFunction and anotherAsynchFunction is changing the values of the data's attribute. After they are done, promise.all() should return all the data. then(function (arrayResults) should take these data and should filter those data that promise.all() has changed and put it into an array called "onlyFilteredResults".

Comment: You're right, `.then(function (arrayResults) {` should be on `Promise.all`